# What should be the shape of spacetime to repel opposite masses from one another?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, curvature

Spin-2 gauge particles like gravitons cause attraction. Attraction in general relativity is accompanied by an appropriate spacetime.

Now if we have positive and negative mass, the gravitons cause repulsion. What would be the appropriate spacetime structure? Is it just one with an hyperbolic space part?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a positive and a negative mass the negative mass will repel the positive one and the positive one will attract the negative one, so together they will form a [runaway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_mass#Runaway_motion) pair.

The gravitational field of an isolated positive mass is described by the Schwarzschild metric with a positive M, and that of a negative mass by the same metric with a negative M.

Since your question is in the categories general relativity and curvature, but not quantum mechanics, the part about the gravitons does not apply here, so my reasoning is geometric and [assuming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_principle)  that the gravitational and inertial mass is the same, but more theories are explored [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=10AP7tio408).